# Чем нарисовать структуру приложения php?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть приложение в моем случае laravel, в процессе его модификации оно сильно разрастается, и становится не удобно работать с кучей файлов и все это в голове держать, если какой то инструмент чтобы можно было отобразить как то структуру приложения в виде блоксхемы например, то есть по всем затронутым и используемым функциям классам итд рисовался график или mindmap?

Comment: `uml` же https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML

Comment: Ок UML, а есть ли какой то пакет который можно поставить через composer и с помощью которого можно эту схему сгенерировать или мне обязательно надо UML изучать? Инструмент готовый есть? Если есть какой лучший?

Comment: можно и автогенерить, например с помощью `doxygen` https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen. Но этап проектирования, на котором и возникают такие диаграммы, должен предшествовать этапу кодирования, на котором возникает документация

Comment: Во чета типа того хочу http://koriym.github.io/print_o/v1/libs/bear.sunday.html думал ктото пользуется просто подобными вещами и хотел поинтересоваться что лучше использовать для Laravel конкретно

Comment: если используете phpStorm, там есть возможность построить диаграмму - правкой кнопкой по файле в списке Diagrams->ShowDiagram

Answer (score 1):

Я умаю стоит попробовать Microsoft Visio.
Ну или Dia под Ubuntu.